# D3D COM Object Pooling

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, memory-management, com

I'm using the following pattern to pool D3D objects globally in my application. Is it a good idea (alternatives)? Is it thread-safe?

```
CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> create_texture(const D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC& desc)
{
    static concurrent_unordered_map<D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC, 
                                    concurrenct_vector<CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>>
                                    d3d_texture2d_desc_hash,
                                    d3d_texture2d_desc_equal_to> pools;

    auto& pool = pools[desc];

    auto it = std::find_if(pool.begin(), pool.end(), [](const CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>& texture)
    {
        assert(texture);

        IUnknown* unknown = texture;
        auto ref_count = unknown.AddRef();

        if(ref_count != 2)
            unknown->Release(); // Only release if we don't want ownership.

        return ref_count == 2;
    });

    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> texture;

    if(it != pool.end())
    {
        texture = *it; // Take ownership.

        IUnknown* unknown = texture;

        // Release the extra ref-count once we have taken ownership.  

    #ifndef _DEBUG
        unknown->Release();     
    #else
        assert(unknown->Release() == 2);
    #endif
    }
    else
    {
        HR(get_default_device()->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &texture));

        pool.push_back(texture);            
    }

    assert(texture);

    return texture;
}
```